# Displaying an array that was created in a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, class, constructor, tostring

SO I need to make a program to display monthly sales from a file. the files have 10 rows and 8 columns. 
I created a class that has a constructor that creates a table, merely of the files exact set up. :

```
public SalesTable(String fileName) {
    Scanner theFile = null;
    try {
        theFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.\n");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // get variables
    myRows = theFile.nextInt();
    myCols = theFile.nextInt();

    // make table
    table = new int[myRows][myCols];

    for(int r = 0; r < myRows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < myCols; c++) {
            table[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < myRows; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < myCols; c++) {
            table[r][c] = theFile.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in main I call it by `SalesTable table = new SalesTable(inFile);`

My problem is, is that I need to have it display exactly what was created in the table, but I cannot get it to print the actually digits in the array inside the table.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? 
thank you in advance!

Comment: So what's your problem? Getting the actual values into the array, or printing them out?

Comment: Can you please share what is the exact issue you are facing?Is it that some of the digits  are missing as compared to the actual file or something else?

Comment: printing them out.

Comment: Can you share the code around your print statement?

Comment: so, if I do: theScreen.println(table); I get SalesTable@677327b6 , I tried Arrays.toString and it did not work

Comment: import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Cars
{
    static PrintStream theScreen = new PrintStream(System.out);
    static Scanner theKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        theScreen.print("\nEnter the name of the file: ");
        String inFile;
        inFile = theKeyboard.nextLine();


        SalesTable table = new SalesTable(inFile);
        theScreen.println(table);

        //theScreen.println(Arrays.toString(table));                                        
    }


}